# Why is vector::clear not working inside foreach loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, foreach

My code:

```
vector<int> v[10];
const int x = 3;
void clearBySimpleLoop(){
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        v[i].clear();
    }
}
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        v[i].push_back(11+i);
        v[i].push_back(11+i+1);
        v[i].push_back(11+i+2);
    }
    for (auto vec : v) vec.clear(); //#01. Contents are not cleared. Size of the contained vectors remains same.
    clearBySimpleLoop(); //#02. Contents are cleared. Size of the contained vectors becomes zero. 
    return 0;
}
```

Question is why does the code inside the *foreach* loop (#01) fails to clear the vector in the array, while a simple *for* loop (#02) does it successfully?

Demo: https://onlinegdb.com/B1m8-2jG4

Comment: I'm sure there are a few duplicates, but short story is that your loop iterates over *values* (i.e. copies) of the vectors.

Comment: ^ That said you should try `for (auto& vec : v) vec.clear();`

Comment: Oh my bad. This should behave same as assigning one vector to another.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write

```
for (auto vec : v) vec.clear(); //
```

then `auto` gets deduced as `std::vector<int>`, hence `vec` are copies of the elements of `v`. You clear the copies, but leave the actual elements unchanged. If you want to operate on the elements themself you have to use references:

```
for (auto& vec : v) vec.clear();
```

My personal rule of thumb is to always mention pointerness, constness and referenceness explicitly when using `auto`. I think it makes usages of `auto` much more readable, but thats just my opinion. Note that here you have no choice, but if you'd follow the rule you could have realized more easily that `vec` are values, not references.